# angular input required field not working

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have a form used for creating a new entity as below:

```
<form #createAppForm="ngForm"
        (ngSubmit)="createApplication(createAppForm.value)"
        autocomplete="false" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group"
         [ngClass]="{'error': createAppForm.controls.applicationName?.invalid && createAppForm.controls.applicationName?.touched}">
    <label for="applicationName">Application Name</label>
    <em *ngIf="createAppForm.controls.applicationName?.invalid && createAppForm.controls.applicationName?.touched">Required</em>
    <input name="applicationName" required id="applicationName" type="text"
           class="form-control" placeholder="Name of application..." />
    </div>
```

I did not use ngModel in the input as the form is supposed to be blank when it comes up, and i'm submitting the createAppForm.value to the ngSubmit.  However, whenever i check the form's valid property:

```
{{createAppForm.invalid}}
```

that is always returning false, even if i click in the input field and click out, without filling anything in.  as a required field should it not return true?

I had used a similar form, editing data, in there i used [ngModel] and that works fine, validates the required field.  Is [ngModel] needed here as well, and if so why?  as i'm passing the form's values in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add ngModel to your input to be able to make use of Angular's form validation.

In a nutshell, ngForm only checks for elements that have an ngModel and a name. Without these, Angular won't validate.

Change it to this:

```
<input name="applicationName" ngModel required id="applicationName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name of application..." />
```

[More info on the official docs.](https://angular.io/guide/forms#the-ngform-directive)

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a formcontrol , in that form control you have to put all the validations.